# Add listener to SVG unload event when SVG is loaded within an <object> tag

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I've got an SVG file that I'm loading within an  element. I attach a listener to the 's `load` event. This event is fired when the SVG file is displayed and ready for any manipulation. After the `load` event I use javascript on my app layer to manipulate the SVG. Hide/show certain elements, animate some elements, add or remove elements. This is all working fine so far and is supported in all the major browsers.

*(In case you're curious, I'm doing this because this SVG is part of a reusable component and this was recommended to me as a way to isolate SVG element IDs from ever overlapping with those in the app or other instances of the SVGs.)*

A problem arises when the `<object>` element or some parent of the element gets detached from the document. This causes the `<object>` to unload. When the detached element is reattached the `<object>` is automatically reloaded and the `load` event fires again.

What I'm concerned about most here is being notified when the `<object>` element is unloaded. I need to run some code to prevent any further SVG manipulation on the unloaded `<object>`.

There is supposedly an ['unload' event](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/script.html#DocumentEvents) that is fired on the `<svg>` when this unloading occurs. I'm able to attach a handle to this event ONLY within the SVG file itself as an attribute. Like:

```
<svg ... onunload="javascript:console.log('THIS WORKS')">
```

However there seems to be no way within javascript on my app layer to attach to this event. Assuming `theObjectEl` is a reference to my `<object>` I'd expect the following to work:

```
theObjectEl.contentDocument.rootElement.addEventListener(
    'unload',
    function() {
        console.log("THIS DOES NOT WORK");
    }
);
```

Whats funny is I'm able to get the `onunload` attribute used in the first example, with `theObjectEl.contentDocument.rootElement.attributes.onunload`. But setting the attribute does absolutely nothing to change the handler of the event.

[A demo showing how the SVG object gets unloaded and reloaded](http://frank-weindel.github.io/svg-unload/)

Any ideas?

**Note:** The SVG is hosted on the same server as my application so there are no cross-origin restrictions at play.

Comment: How is your element unloaded, I'm not able to reproduce even with the attribute.

Comment: Thanks. Here is a demo that shows whats going on. http://frank-weindel.github.io/svg-unload/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

Got it : `svgDocument.defaultView.addEventListener('unload' , function(){console.log('Gotcha!')})`

You have to attach the event to the `documentElement`'s [`defaultView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/defaultView) property.

Comment: I've basically got that part figured out. However I need the unload event so that I can unsubscribe some event handlers etc to prevent them from modifying an SVG that is no longer there.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks! I've updated my example to illustrate the unload event working in the console. This works in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, but not IE9 or IE10 (go figure). But this might be as good as it gets.